Can i perform a chargeback if a store refuses a return?
I purchased a Dual Pack (memory expansion card, hard drive) for my Xbox at Walmart. I got the item home and got it out of the package and noticed there were items missing. I scrambled for the receipt and returned it to Walmart, hoping to get a refund when instead I was made to feel like I was the thief! The customer service man looked over the box and was comparing serial numbers and replied they didn't match. My girlfriend waved down a manager and he came to assist his employee. They both looked and said again the serial numbers didn't match. And than both proceeded to insinuate that I was the one who took the missing item and swapped the hard drive! They refused my refund (because of the mismatched serial numbers) and told me there was nothing they could do. Later after I did research, I found out that when there are multiple items packaged together the serial numbers change to accommodate extra items.. Ive been told to do a charge back Someone Help!

Technically, only the credit card company can do a chargeback. The customer (you) can file a "dispute" with the credit card company, which may result in chargeback.

This is very common in the age of "risk free" returns. Especially for electronics where you can easily buy an item, swap for a (similar looking) much cheaper electronic, then return that to the store. People make a living off of doing stuff like this.
Yes, a credit card charge-back is the next step in this process. Be prepared to send your CC issuer a receipt as well as a written description of what the box should have contained and what it actually contained.
You could also try a different Walmart. Customer service there might be more understanding. Although, there is a chance they will issue a gift card for the amount instead of a full refund.

If it was a sealed package, you can also contact the manufacturer and ask for replacement of the missing parts, assuming this was sold to you as new rather than b-stock. If you got an "opened box" discount, however, missing components are part of the risk; a good store will inspect before re-shelving and label it with a list of missing parts  but a discount outlet like Walmart isn't going to hire or pay for those skills. One reason to sometimes pay more is to get a more responsible vendor  (There's one outlet in my area that is notorious for re-shelving uninspected; I won't buy there.)
